# Skype Interview scheduled with the Italian consulate in Bangalore

Tags: visas, schengen, italy

My husband and I are travelling via a tour operator to Italy, Austria, France and Switzerland. We will be extending our trip for 3 days after to visit Amsterdam. The train tickets, hotel bookings etc. for this leg were also provided.

We both work and have tax returns etc. in place. We both also have valid US visas (tourist, not sure if this helps but we were asked to provide the photocopy at VFS).

I submitted all my documents at VFS and when I checked my status I see we have been called for a Skype interview on the 4th of April. My travel is on the 24th of April 2017.

What can I expect at the Skype interview and what kind of additional documents should we take (since every conceivable thing was already submitted!)? Would marriage certificate, child's birth certificate help? (We aren't taking our daughter along on this trip.)

Comment: Who is "we"? do they want a joint interview with you together? (most unseemly) Or "we" means each of you separately has been called in for an interview?

Comment: They'll probably want to see if you're genuine visitors i.e know where you are visiting, why and what you plan to do. Make sure your answers line up with those that you have already provided.

Comment: Just a word of warning, I am not at all sure about this: consulates doing Skype interviews for visa sounds a bit *sketchy* to me. It does happen at times but I would not have expected it e.g. for Schengen, i.e. they would at least use another videochat system than Skype. So why don't you **double-check that you are not being scammed**? If you applied directly with the embassy then you are likely fine, if you went through an agent, further inquiries may be in order. Again, its just a thought of mine, it may all be fine or all be messed up, I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, having searched a bit more, the [Italian embassy](http://www.ambdhaka.esteri.it/ambasciata_dhaka/en/informazioni_e_servizi/visti/) actually uses and endorses [VFS](http://www.vfsglobal-it-bd.com/) so if that is where you applied then my last comment should be neglected.

Comment: I checked with the VFS chat helpline,Skpe interviews seem to be a thing :-/ Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 3):

This interview is more likely to ascertain your motives for the journey and to be satisfied that you will return after your tour.

Surely if it is Skype interview you are doing it from your home and don't need to take any additional documents as mentioned or are we missing something here?

Comment: The interview is actually at the VFS office and we have been asked to carry our original offer letter from the company we work for.I cant find much info about this Skype business online though :-/

Comment: I would suggest you take all documents you think will be required and some - better to err on the side of caution - including your offer letters, payslips, bank statements, tax returns, utility bills, property documents - anything and everything you can show to prove that you have strong ties to your country and that you will definitely return after your tour